# Rails ActiveRecord writes encrypted attribute but does not read it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `Patient` model backed by a `patients` Postgres database table. It has an attribute `national_id` that is encrypted by the lockbox gem and therefore stored in the `national_id_ciphertext` column. This attribute is saved/updated fine and I can verify this in the database.

However when I read this record back, the national_id attribute is not included.

Rails console:

```zsh
pry(main)> p = Patient.find(8)
=> #<Patient id: 8, name: "Øyvind Hansen", address: nil, address_directions: nil, zip: "0667", city: "Oslo", phone_number: "+4712345678", email: "oyvind@test.com", created_at: "2020-09-05 19:41:55", updated_at: "2020-09-05 20:45:46", referral_id: nil>

pry(main)> p.national_id
=> "12345678912"
```

The schema is:

```ruby
create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "zip"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "email"
    t.text "national_id_ciphertext" # Saved, but not retrieved
    t.bigint "referral_id"
    t.index ["referral_id"], name: "index_patients_on_referral_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

The implementation of Lockbox encryption is very simple and straight from the basic example from [the docs](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox).

```ruby
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
    encrypts :national_id
end
```

Any idea why the national_id accessor created by Lockbox are not included in enumerable model attributes?

Comment: The `national_id` is not a db column, therefore not shown in the basic output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in your own test, the value is available.  `national_id` is an available method on the object but is not a DB attribute. You can always retrieve it with dot notation e.g. `my_patient.national_id` but not through hash notation

```
my_patient.national_id
=> "12345678912"

my_patient["national_id"]
=> nil
```

This shouldn't normally be a problem, just use dot notation.

If the problem is transposing into json you can add methods to your json call...

```
my_patient.to_json(methods: [:national_id])
```

Or you can modify your `to_json` to include it always

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord
   
  def to_json(options={})
    super options.merge({methods: [:national_id]})
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any equivalent to this method for making sure it's included in basic lookups, like `Patient.find(8, methods: [:national_id)`(Obviously I know this doesn't work, but I'm trying to explain what I am trying to do).

Comment: But it IS available.  `my_patient = Patient.find(8); my_patient.name # this returns "Øyvind Hansen"; my_patient.national_id # this returns "12345678912"`  Everything you need is there.  The patient object is a collection of attributes AND methods and you can call on either.

Comment: Just include the `@patient.national_id` on your show pages, it's there for you.

Comment: Thanks. I know it's there, but it's not included when the model is serialized, for instance when passing it to React as a prop.

Comment: Override your  `to_json` method to include it on every to_json call... see the last part of my modified answer.